# placeholder image for background-image?

Tags: html, css, pug

```
.mydiv(style="background-image: url('"+pic+"');" onerror="this.style.background-image:url('http://www.naijaticketshop.com/images/default_profile.jpg'); ")
```

I'm aware you would use onerror for an  placeholder, but this doesn't seem to be working for background-image. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="my.png" onerror="this.src = 'http://www.naijaticketshop.com/images/default_profile.jpg';" />
```

or with jquery

```
// Replace source
$('.mydiv').error(function(){
        $(this).attr('background-image', 'url(http://www.naijaticketshop.com/images/default_profile.jpg)');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `this.style.backgroundImage`, *not* `this.style.background-image`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use onerror on `<div>`. onerror can only use on `<img>, <object>, <script>, <style>`. So, Need to replace with `<img>` tag. If you don't want to replace with it, 
I found that on stackoverflow. [How to replace nonexistent images with a placeholder in asynchronous loading from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265839/how-to-replace-nonexistent-images-with-a-placeholder-in-asynchronous-loading-fro)